# bulk insert into postgres db using fastapi and returing ids

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

My goal is to insert values in a db table using fastapi `post` method and return the primary key `id` from the db auto generated ids as a response model. I have successfully executed the post method but I'm not returning anything, how can i return this data ?

This is my `models.py`:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped,mapped_column,DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy import Identity,Enum
from pydantic import BaseModel, ConfigDict, HttpUrl, EmailStr
import enum

class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass

class Color(str,enum.Enum):
    RED = 'RED'
    BLUE = 'BLUE'

class Example(Base):
    __tablename__='example'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Identity(always=True),primary_key=True)
    colors: Mapped[Color] = mapped_column(Enum(Color))

class ExampleBase(BaseModel):
    model_config = ConfigDict(from_attributes=True)
    colors: Color

class ExampleCreate(ExampleBase):
    id: int
```

And this is `main.py`:

```
from db import engine,get_db
from models import *
from fastapi import FastAPI,Depends,Query,Path,Body,Cookie,Header,Response,Form,File,UploadFile,HTTPException,Request
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse, RedirectResponse
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession
from sqlalchemy import select,update,insert
from contextlib import asynccontextmanager
from typing import Annotated,Union,List,Any
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
import uvicorn
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta
from uuid import UUID



@asynccontextmanager
async def lifespan(app: FastAPI):
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)
    yield

app = FastAPI(lifespan=lifespan) # type: ignore


@app.post("/create_color/") #,response_model=list[ExampleCreate]
async def create_colors(colors: list[ExampleBase],db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_db)):
    stmt = (insert(Example),[_.model_dump() for _ in colors])
    await db.execute(*stmt)
    await db.commit()
    # How to return a list of the inserted objects with their ID ????????????
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've managed to do that in the following way:

```
@app.post("/create_color/",response_model=list[ExampleCreate]) 
async def create_colors(colors: list[ExampleBase],db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_db)):
    models = [Example(**_.model_dump()) for _ in colors]
    db.add_all(models)
    await db.commit()
    for model in models:
        await db.refresh(model)
    return models
```

Only drawback here is that the instances of `Example` need to be refreshed one by one. As of my knowledge there isn't a `refresh_all()` method in sqlalchemy.